# How to set specific width and height of a div element when media queries are present in css file?

Tags: html, css, media-queries, seo, pagespeed

I am trying to resolve the avoid large layout shifts in PagespeedInsights
The solution is to set with and height of the below div element.

```html
<div id="HomeNewsEventsWrapper" class="section fixedheight1 introduction table">
```

```css
@media (min-width:0px) and (max-width:580px) {
    #HomeNewsEventsWrapper{
    }
}
```

However, It will also affect the media queries(If the viewport is greater than 580px in real life)

Also, how can I set with and height for every viewport?

I also tries setting height and width to auto but it does not work.

Comment: you could try to use `@media only screen and (max-width: 580px) { ... }`. Setting a viewport on height is rarely used. Why do you want to set a media query for hight as well?

Comment: The thing is that the pagspeed insights requires that I set the specific width and height of the div element.

What should I set the width and height of div element  for max-width:580px

Comment: please elaborate further. I have no idea what you trying to do or attempt. So just throwing that you need to set a specific height and width is far too broad. Currently to me the question is like how long is a hallway if the width is 20 feets. There is no default relation between width and height.

Comment: What I need to do do is set the height and width of the div element 

However, if I do that then it will affect the media queries.
How do I fix the issue?

Let's say that the width is greater than max-width in media-queries. What to do then?

Comment: You're going into circles - there is no sense in continuing this. We cannot tell you what to do if you can't tell us the exact requirements and relations to each other. There is **no** relation between the height and width of a document by default. So we cannot tell you what height to use and at which width if you can't tell us the relation between each other.

Comment: I want to fix width of div element.
For Example: "style=24px";

However waht id max-width in media query is greater than 24px

This is my query

Comment: media queries apply to the cirteria of the viewport/screen such as print media, width and heights, touchscreens. It does not apply based on conditions of certain elements

Answer (score 1):

First step Set a fixed height and width for the element in css file , Adjust the height and width for smaller viewports

```css
#HomeNewsEventsWrapper{
  height: 200px;
  width: 100%;
  background:red;
}
@media (max-width: 580px) {
  #HomeNewsEventsWrapper {
    height: 150px; 
    width: 100%; 
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="HomeNewsEventsWrapper" class="section fixedheight1 introduction table">
```

Comment: ```
@media (max-width: 580px) {
  #HomeNewsEventsWrapper {
    height: 150px; 
    width: 100%; 
  }
```
```
#HomeNewsEventsWrapper{
  height: 200px;
  width: 100%;
  background:red;
}
```

How did you come up with height and width values in media queries and HomeNewsEventsWrapper?

Comment: `width: 100%` has already been declared. Redeclaring it is just useless or redundant in the best case. The modern approach is to go mobile first.

Comment: How did you calculate the height value of 200px and 150px?

Comment: The modern approach is to go mobile first.

What does this mean?

Answer (score 1):

So it sounds like you have late-loading content which then expands and pushes other content off screen. This is a bad user experience and what CLS is designed to measure. So it's best to reserve the space needed by that `div` when it's first create, even if you will only be able to fill it in later. So PSI is basically telling you to set the dimensions of it to do that, and you'll avoid the CLS.

If your `height` should be fixed then just set that using CSS. And you can set different `height`s in different media queries.

If you want the width and height to be a fixed ratio, then you should use the CSS `aspect-ratio` property. See [this article](https://web.dev/articles/aspect-ratio), and [the MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/aspect-ratio). This is good in examples where the width is a percentage of the viewport and the height should be based on that, rather than a fixed with.

For example, a `1 / 1` aspect ratio means if the width is `100px`, then the height will also be set to `100px`. A `1 / 2` aspect ratio (which can also be written `0.5` means if the width is `100px`, then the height will be doubled to `200px`. As your width changes, the height can automatically be calculated while maintaining this fixed aspect ratio.

This is basically what the browser does for you when you provide it with a `width` and `height` as described in this article (that I authored): https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2020/03/setting-height-width-images-important-again/

This is also the advice given in the [Optimize CLS guide](https://web.dev/articles/optimize-cls) from Google (full disclosure: I maintain this guide now). Search in that article and you will find are several mentions of `aspect-ratio`.

Comment: And you can set different heights in different media queries.

Can you give just one example with a div element

```
<div id="HomeNewsEventsWrapper" class="section fixedheight1 introduction table">
```

These are two media queries
```
@media (min-width:0px) and (max-width:767px) {}
```
```
@media (max-width:1024px) and (min-width:768px) {}
```

Comment: Ahmed's answer already shows an example if how to do this.

Comment: How did you calculate the height value of 200px and 150px?

Comment: The modern approach is to go mobile first. What does this mean?